# aria-required on jquery submit form

Tags: javascript, jquery

let say i have the following form

```
<form action="post">
     <label for="firstName">First name:</label>
     <input id="firstName" type="text" aria-required="true" />
     <input type="submit" value="submit">
 </form>
```

and with jQuery i want to do `$.post()`, i use following jQuery script

```
jQuery(function($){
        $(SUBMIT_BTN).on('click', function(e){
            var data = $('form').serialize() + '&action=save_customer';
            $.ajax({
                url: MYRUL,
                method: 'POST',
                data:  data,
                success: function(response){
                    $('form').trigger('reset');
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

with that script the aria-required is not working any longer. how to trigger validation in this case?

PS: I want to use this `aria-required`, avoiding jQuery plugins

Comment: Why not using `required` attribute instead? Why binding click event on the FORM, why not using instead submit event?

Comment: sorry, my mistake. it was a submit button, edited.

Comment: Why don't you use `required` insted of `aria-required="true"`?

Comment: does `required` will do the validation by default? BTW, i changed the code myself, attaching `onsubmit` on the `form` instead of attach click event on the submit button. the validation is now working..hope this help others with the same prob

Comment: Is aria-required supposed to do anything anyway? I personally use aria-required to check if field is required and then check for it with jQuery but I'm not expecting the browser to do anything with it by default.

Answer (score 0):

use `required="required"` instead of `aria-required="true"`